# How to implement AppCheck in react native using react-native-firebase library from rnfirebase.io?

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-firebase, firebase-app-check

I've been trying to remove reCaptcha from firebase phone authentication and the only way nowadays, earlier SafetyNet was another, is to use Play Integriti which supposedly needs AppCheck. I've been stuck on this for some time and would love it if someone could help. Thanks.

AppCheck API is all over the place.

Comment: have you found a solution here?